# How to Increase build vnext build agent execution time?

Tags: tfsbuild

I am running a large suite of tests on my build server and it takes longer than an hour to get through them all. It is currently failing after an hour stating this:

> The job running on agent xAgentNamex has exceeded the maximum
>   execution time of 01:00:00.

I thought it would be in the `User capabilities` settings for the build agent but I could not see anything there.

How can I increase this limit?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is under the settings of your build definition: General->Build job timeout in minutes.
[image]

Comment: I know this is old, but I love when someone takes a screen shot. So much easier with visual stuff.

Comment: In VSTS and TFS 2017+ this settings is found in the Options tab (the General tab does not exist anymore).

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a LOT!